# Android: Toggle Accelerometer Rotation State Setting

Tags: android, rotation, settings, default, accelerometer

I've found load of examples of setting rotation *within* your application but what I'm having trouble with is toggling the phones setting located at: **Settings, Display, Auto-rotate screen (checkbox)**.
I want to be able to check the phones rotation state, set it to it's opposite (auto or off) and then close the app.

This is what I've got:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Rotation extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try{
        if  (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1){
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);
            Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        else{
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);
            Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Try failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

if you need to know any more info just let me know :)
 
Any help is appreciated, it's stressing me **out!!**

Comment: Is it working? What happens if not?

Comment: Nope, not working. It just shows the catch and then closes. I've tried moving the numeric values around but no change.
Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for the trick... I spent hours searching for this...Thanks

Comment: it will only work for api < 4.2. because write setting doesn't work any more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set the correct permission?

I didn't and the exception detail message says,

`"Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=306, uid=10037 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"`

That pretty much sums it up.